# How to get no of results in shards from solr and store in hashmap array

Tags: java, solr

I have response data from solr for `resp.getResponse().get("shards.info")` as following :

```
 {
xyz1={

     numFound=149040,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz1,
     time=3
},

xyz2={
     numFound=12414,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz2,
     time=5
},

xyz3={
     numFound=62175,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz13,
     time=6
},

xyz4={
     numFound=200572,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz14,
     time=4
},

xyz5={
     numFound=32853,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz5,
     time=5
},

xyz6={
     numFound=73443,
     maxScore=1.0,
     shardAddress=http://xyz6,
     time=5
}
 }
```

```
        for (SolrDocument solrDocument:resp.getResponse().get("shards.info")) 
        { 
            documentsList.add(solrDocument);
        }


 but found this error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"
How to pass those values into documentsList_shards please help me
```

Comment: But shards info isn't a document in Solr (which is what `SolrDocument` represents). What do you _actually_ want to achieve?

Comment: i need to get number of result for each core using `solrQuery.set("shards.info","true");` from `resp.getResponse().get("shards.info")` i got the above result now i want to store in arraylist or similar kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps some, if there is an improvement from Please you are welcome

```
    NamedList<Object> report = (NamedList<Object>)resp.getResponse().get("shards.info");
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> coreIterator = report.iterator();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    while(coreIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> core = coreIterator.next();
        String core_name=(core.getKey().toString()).replace("abcc","");
        NamedList<Object> report_in = (NamedList<Object>)core.getValue();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> coreIterator_in = report_in.iterator();
        while(coreIterator_in.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> core_in = coreIterator_in.next();
            if(core_in.getKey().equals("numFound"))
            {
                String numFound=core_in.getValue().toString();
                hm.put(core_name, numFound); 
            }
        }
    }
```